# FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Could not load root certificates from the bundle. SSL cannot work

Tags: xcode, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a React Native Application and I already managed to run it on android platform without any problem. However I got an error in xcode. It is building the project and running it but after I pass the firebase authentication part, it results in failure.

Failure:

```
*** Assertion failure in std::string firebase::firestore::remote::LoadGrpcRootCertificate()(), ..myProject/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/firebase/firestore/remote/grpc_root_certificate_finder_apple.mm:61
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Could not load root certificates from the bundle. SSL cannot work. (expected path)'
```

My Podfile:

```
# File contents of "ios/Podfile"
platform :ios, '9.0'
 
target 'myProject' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'DevSupport',
    # the following ones are the ones taken from "Libraries" in Xcode:
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTBlob',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]
 
  # the following dependencies are dependencies of React native itself.
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec'
 
  # your other libraries will follow here!
  pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4.0'
  pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/ios'
  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'
  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'
  #pod 'react-native-google-places', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-google-places' #there is no such .podspec file add manually
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces' 
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

end
 
# The following is needed to ensure the "archive" step works in XCode.
# It removes React from the Pods project, as it is already included in the main project.
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end

install! 'cocoapods',
         :deterministic_uuids => false,
         :integrate_targets => false
```

Related questions that i couldn't find the solution:

> https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2177
>
> https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2385

Comment: Same thing is happening to me using the ios sdk native. Dunno how to debug really.

Comment: It appears to happen on the current users token refresh.that is far as I have traced it.

Comment: I only have one user atm, I'm going to try with a different user to se if it is specific to that token refresh somehow. -- that made no difference. I'm stuck as well.

Comment: I get stucked as well .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ''' I've been coresponding with the firebase-ios-sdk crew and I
>   believe we have dentified the issue, and have a workaround for now.
>
> The issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2604
>
> The workaround: Locate the 'gRPCCertificates.bundle' file.  Locate the
>   root.pem file inside it. Add the root.pem file to your ios app under
>   the project navigator. ENSURE its target membership is checked for
>   your app target. ENSURE under Build Phase, 'Copy Bundle Resources' for
>   your app target that 'root.pem' is added
>
> Wouldn't hurt to clean the build folder probably. Build and run and
>   you should no longer see the error. (PS SO this is not code.) '''
>
> Blockquote
>   PS SO, none of that resembles code in any way.

Comment: Thank you Jimmy. You solved it right? Could you please explain what do you mean with locate that files. I opened xcode and I found that files you mentioned under 'Pods/Products/gRPCCertificates.bundle' and 'Pods/Pods/gRPC-C++/Resources/roots.pem'. I tried to do something with them but it gives an error 'Too long file path name'

Comment: My Solution: Go to your Project Navigator myProject/myProject -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> Add(plus sign) and select roots.pem

Comment: still cannot for my case

Answer (score 3):

***I 100% solved to problem***

**update** your pods

then make sure to **delete** the app from the phone/simulator

and **run** the app and it will work fine

Comment: this was really the solution... Its just working if deleting the app from phone / simulator before starting again :p

Comment: I am not using Pods?